# How to configure CRM Ribbon xml to display a ribbon button for an Entity only when it is being viewed in the context of a particular parent entity

Tags: ribbon, dynamics-crm-2011

### What I'm Trying To Do

I've got a CRM entity (LocationSettings) that is displayed as an associated Sub Grid on another entity (Location).   I want to add a button to the subgrid ribbon for the LocationSettings entity that will basically delete all LocationSettings for the Location the user is currently viewing.

### Where I'm At

I'm using the Visual Ribbon Editor for CRM 2011, and I have been able to successfully create the button, and add it to the ribbon, but when I try to add a display rule to only allow the button to show up when the user is on the Location entity form, viewing the LocationSettings entity associated subgrid, I'm at a complete lost, and everything I try just results in the button not getting displayed.

My current best guess is to add a display rule with these values:
Entity Name: location
Applies To: PrimaryEntity
Context: Form

Anyone know what I should be doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after digging around I finally found my issue.  I was using an [`EntityRule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309418.aspx) display rule, when I needed to be using a [`FormEntityContextRule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328247.aspx) with location as my entity name.  It works now.  Hopefully this will help someone else down the road that manages to make the same dumb mistake...