# CRM 2011 - Show Ribbon Button for Specific Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, ribbon, crm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure CRM Ribbon xml to display a ribbon button for an Entity only when it is being viewed in the context of a particular parent entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195302/how-to-configure-crm-ribbon-xml-to-display-a-ribbon-button-for-an-entity-only-wh)

I'm trying to use the "DisplayRule" for hiding/showing buttons for a specific entity!  I have a subgrid on the "Registration" form and in that subgrid the user has to choose some items to add in a Basket.

But the button I've created for the basket, is shown on every form, where is subgrid is created for that basket.

The button only needs to appear on the "Registration"-Form and on the other entities the button shouldn't appear.  I used the following XML-statement, but it doesn't seems to work :

```
      <DisplayRules>
        <DisplayRule Id="A.HideButtonOnOtherForm">
          <EntityRule AppliesTo="PrimaryEntity" EntityName="ave_registration" Context="Form"  />
        </DisplayRule>
      </DisplayRules>
```

The above XML-statements hides the button for ALL entities... But It should show it only on the Registration.. What am I doing wrong? ave_registration is the name of my Registration Entity :)